# Good MVC framework for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller

Do you know a decent MVC framework for AS3? I am currently looking into PureMVC but I need some reassurance that it's the best choice.

Do I really need to use a framework? or would it be better for me to implement MVC myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming by AS3 you mean flex/AS3.  Cairngorm is the defacto standard and was written by adobe consulting; Hence, you will find a lot of community support.  There are a few others including PureMVC.  There is an article on the adobe/flex website which gives a good description of all of them.

Comment: Well, my platform is actually Flash. And, as I understand, Cairngorm uses Flex's libraries.

I think that PureMVC would be my choice..
Thanks!

Comment: Cairngorm...the flashbacks are coming to me. I vote for mvc but not PureMVC. Simply make 3 folders/root packages and call them view / mode / controller and organize yourself thusly. I sometimes put those names at the start of the class's name like ModelDollar, ModelEuro and ViewCurency or something of the sorts.

Answer (score 1):

i followed MVC Design Pattern in AS3

i.e,

The model represents the information (the data) of the application and the business rules used to manipulate the data

The view corresponds to elements of the user interface such as text, checkbox items, and so forth

The controller manages details involving the communication to the model of user actions such as keystrokes and mouse movements.

if you have any doubts about implemention of MVC you can refer actionscriptworkouts.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0):

Carnigorm and PureMVC are good choices, but my personal opinion is that Robotlegs is far easier to work with.

http://www.robotlegs.org